# Rails Routes: Redirecting to Routes That Require Sign In

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have several actions that require authentication. For example, to create a new favorite or todo:

```
resources :users, :has_many => [ :favs, :todos ]
```

What I usually do is add a before filter to the appropriate actions that checks if the user is signed in. If they're not the filter saves the target URL and redirects them to a sign in page. After signing in they are redirected to the saved URL.

But, given the above routes, this is not possible since a user must be signed in in order to even generate the URL.

Does this mean that I should add routed to the `:favs` and `:todos` controllers:
`/favs/new` and `/todos/new` just to deal with the cases?

Otherwise I'd have to build a mapping of  URL key words to do the redirects: `/login?return_to=new_todo` instead of `/login?return_to=http://localhost/bob/todo/new`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the bigger picture of what you are trying to achieve, but I would highly recommend checking out an authentication gem like Devise.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

It is a lot of work to handle authentication properly (and securely), and unless you have unique circumstances, it's likely not worth the time to reinvent the wheel here.

Also, Devise handles your mentioned functionality well.